# Different behavior when using vsnprintf on msvc and gcc

Tags: c++, g++, printf

I have the following code to append a buffer using `vsnprintf()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

using namespace std;

void MyPrintFunc(char *buffer, size_t sizeOfBuffer, const char* format, ...)
{
   va_list arg;
   va_start(arg, format);

   vsnprintf(buffer, sizeOfBuffer, format, arg);

   va_end(arg);
}

int main()
{
   char buffer[1000] = { 0 };
   const char* abc = "abc";
   const char* def = "def";

   MyPrintFunc(buffer, 1000, "%s", abc);
   MyPrintFunc(buffer, 1000, "%s%s", buffer, def);
   printf("%s\n", buffer);
   return 0;
}
```

It gave different output on both Windows and Linux.
On Windows (using msvc-14.0 compiler), it give desired output of `abcdef`.

But on Linux (using gcc-5.4), it only print output of `def`.

How can I get the correct output?

Comment: `vsnprintf` is defined to behave like `snprintf`, save for the argument provision which is done via a `va_arg` list. `snprintf` specifically calls out in the language standard, "If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.". Your `buffer` is both the target buffer and a formatted input argument source in your second call, thereby invoking *undefined behavior*. From that, attempting to make sense of the output is pointless; you'd be looking for definition where none exists.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the same buffer as both an output and input to vsnprintf.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the input.

My solution to this is to create a copy of the buffer if user of the MyPrintFunc() used it to append buffer:

```
void MyPrintFunc(char *buffer, size_t sizeOfBuffer, const char* format, ...)
{
   va_list arg;
   va_list arg_copy;

   va_start(arg, format);
   va_copy(arg_copy, arg);

   if (buffer == va_arg(arg, char*))
   {
      char temp[strlen(buffer)];
      strcpy(temp, buffer);
      MyPrintFunc(buffer, sizeOfBuffer, format, temp, va_arg(arg,char*));
   }
   else
   {
      vsnprintf(buffer, sizeOfBuffer, format, arg_copy);
   }

   va_end(arg);
   va_end(arg_copy);
}
```